# php if statement is not functioning when using strstr

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$test123 = "<ssl_result_message>APPROVAL</ssl_result_message>";

$value = strstr($test123, "<ssl_result_message>"); //gets all text from <ssl_result_message> forward

$value = strstr($value, "</ssl_result_message>", true); //gets all text before </ssl_result_message>

echo $value,"<br>";

if ($value == 'APPROVAL') {
echo 'Transaction is APPROVED!';}


else{
echo 'Transaction is DECLINED';}
```

The echo value part echos "APPROVAL" just like I expected it to. But the if statement is not working. I keep getting mixed results. I have tried =  ==  and ===  .

If i use $value = "APPROVAL"; instead of the test123 with strstr and test, it works as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why did you edit your question to already include the answer? This is not helpful at all.

Comment: It's helpful for someone looking for the answer. Here let me remove it and the next person can sift through all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your debugging message, `string(28) "APPROVAL"` your string is:

```
<ssl_result_message>APPROVAL
```

not `APPROVAL`, your browser probably is hiding the element. You could either strip the elements if that is really what your complete string is:

```
$value = strip_tags($test123);
```

or you could use a parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($test123);
libxml_clear_errors();
$ssl = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ssl_result_message');
$value = $ssl->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

As for an explanation for what your current code did...

The function is defined to

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.

So your searched for `<ssl_result_message>`, found it and returned that and the remaining string:

```
<ssl_result_message>APPROVAL</ssl_result_message>
```

you then took off the `</ssl_result_message>` which left you with the 28 character string. A parser is really the best way to handle these type of processes going forward.

Comment: It still shows in the source code as before but the if statement now works exactly as I need it to. Perfectly executed and straight forward answer. Could not ask for anything more. Thank you!

Comment: I was under the impression that when I search for <ssl_result_message> that it will find that entire string and start with the following text. and then searching for the closing tag leaves me with just the "APPROVAL". The regular echo was showing it correctly as "APPROVAL" but not in the source code. I am going to read more on the subject.

Comment: Don't debug with your browser it won't show you the real output, or don't use the rendered DOM. Here's a demo https://3v4l.org/X9ptg but reallllly you shouldn't use `strstr` or any string modification functions for this. It is a structured language, deal with it as such.

Comment: When I tested $value = strip_tags($test123);     in my production environment I found the same issue. But when I said $value = strip_tags($value);    it then started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try using strip_tags instead of strstr. Also, use strcmp for string comparision

```
$value = strip_tags($test123);

if (strcmp(trim($value),'APPROVAL')==0) {
   echo 'Transaction is APPROVED!';}
else{
   echo 'Transaction is DECLINED';}
```

Comment: I am still getting 

APPROVAL
Transaction is DECLINED

I tried echo strlen($value),"<br>"; and it is showing 28 still. Weird but the regular echo shows "APPROVAL" and when i double click the words I dont see any extra spaces that way either.

Comment: Are you compelled to use strstr ? Why won't you use preg_match or strip_tags. edited above example using strip_tags

Comment: @joshrt24. It is awful that you chose another answer while I was working for last 30 mins

Comment: @RinsadAhmed You could have stopped when you saw my answer worked. Just changing to match my answer isn't how SO works..(and that wasn't the best approach)

Comment: @user3783243 I was working with his problem. I had nothing to do what you were doing.

Comment: user3783243 provided me the strip_tags answer first ( at least I seen his first) and tested it. I did not realize I could not mark two answers as correct. Both are sufficient but I can not mark both it seems.

Comment: at least you would give me a vote. I never copied his work. I worked it out on my way

Comment: I have less than 15 rep but I did vote.  Your work is not unappreciated . Both of you helped solve and confirm my problem and that was the goal here.